# how can I multiply each number in a list by it's list index?

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a list, for example:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and I want to multiply each of them by it's list index:

```
[3*0, 4*1, 5*2, 6*3]
```

I'm a bigener in python and I want to solve this with for loops and without using any built in functions. it will be really helpful if you help me, thank you.

```
n=0

for z in range (0, len(numbers)):

    numbers[n]=numbers[(z * n)]

    n+=1
```

this is what I have wrote already and it doesn't work.

Comment: Voting to close as this does read like it is homework and @sam has shown no attempt at a problem solution.

Comment: Write a for loop. Look into the `enumerate` function to easily get the index.

Comment: @MichaelKaras yes this is a small part of my homework and I have tried solving it for days. I thought you could ask any kind of programming related questions here!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in this line:

```
 numbers[n]=numbers[(z * n)]
```

you want to change numbers[n] to the number at the index n by n

so an alternative may be

```
for n in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[n] = numbers[n] * n
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I thought if I put the n out of the bracket it won't work, but it works fine.

Comment: no problem! would you mind upvoting me and giving me best answer?